# Finding Ancestry Path of a merge in LibGit2Sharp

Tags: c#, libgit2, libgit2sharp

In Git, I can get all of the commits relevant to a merge with the following commands:

```sh
bases=$(git merge-base --all --octopus A B C)

git log --pretty=%H --ancestry-path A B C --not $bases
echo $bases
```

Is there an equivalent to this in LibGit2Sharp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`repo.ObjectDatabase.FindMergeBase()` should help tackle the first step

```
/// <summary>
/// Find the best possible merge base given two or more <see cref="Commit"/> according
/// to the <see cref="MergeBaseFindingStrategy"/>.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="commits">
/// The <see cref="Commit"/>s for which to find the merge base.
/// </param>
/// <param name="strategy">
/// The strategy to leverage in order to find the merge base.
/// </param>
/// <returns>The merge base or null if none found.</returns>
public virtual Commit FindMergeBase(IEnumerable<Commit> commits,
     MergeBaseFindingStrategy strategy)
```

`repo.Commits.QueryBy(new CommitFilter { Since = commits, Until = bestMergeBase });` would be the way to enumerates the relevant commits.

### Update following your comment

> Does that replicate the `--all` flag of `git merge-base`?

No. Only the "best" computed merge base will be returned by this method.

A **[git_merbe_bases_many()](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/include/git2/merge.h#L388-L401)** function exists in libgit2 that would allow to replicate `--all`. However, it's not been bound to libGit2Sharp yet. Would you be interested in it, please log a feature request in the **[issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues)**

Comment: Does that replicate the `--all` flag of `git merge-base`?

Comment: @JohnGietzen Good point! The answer has been updated following your comment.